# Code a recursive asterisk function in prolog with spaces

Tags: prolog

I am to write a predicate in prolog which takes an integer X and outputs a mirrored asterisk pattern:

```
******
**  **
*    *
*    *
**  **
******
```

Comment: You need to calculate the number of spaces in the line, then have (for example) three separate printing predicates: pre/stars, mid/spaces, post/stars.

Comment: This identical question and result came up a few days ago, and I had offered basically the same comment at that time that Tomas just offered. Did that question get deleted?

Comment: Yes, twice, I believe.

Comment: @lurker if you have it in your browser history (and it has an answer) you can have it undeleted by a moderator, by giving them the URL on meta.

Comment: `midSpaces(N2, N3)` is called with `N2` unbound.  So `not(N2 = N3)` in your `midSpaces(N2, N3) :- ...` predicate will ALWAYS fail. That's because Prolog will always be able to unify `N2` and `N3` since one is a variable, which means `N2 = N3` always succeeds, and thus `not(N2 = N3)` always fails.

Answer (score 0):

This program prints the desired pattern (i've replaced space with undescore):

```
printStar(0).
printStar(N):-
    write('*'),
    N1 is N-1,
    printStar(N1).

printSpaces(0).
printSpaces(N):-
    write('_'),
    N1 is N-1,
    printSpaces(N1).

printUpperPattern(0,_).
printUpperPattern(N,R):-
    N > 0,
    Spaces is 2*R - 2,
    printStar(N),
    printSpaces(Spaces),
    printStar(N),
    nl,
    N1 is N-1,
    R1 is R+1,
    printUpperPattern(N1,R1).

printLowerPattern(0,_).
printLowerPattern(N,R):-
    N > 0,
    Spaces is 2*N - 2,
    printStar(R),
    printSpaces(Spaces),
    printStar(R),
    nl,
    N1 is N-1,
    R1 is R+1,
    printLowerPattern(N1,R1).

pattern(N):-
    printUpperPattern(N,1),
    printLowerPattern(N,1).
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
rectangle(Len) :-
    Max is Len/2 - 1,
    forall(between(0,Max,I), write_line(Max, I)),
    forall(between(0,Max,I), (J is Max-I, write_line(Max, J))).

write_line(Max, N) :-
    Stars is Max+1 - N,
    Spaces is 2 * N,
    forall(between(1,Stars, _), write('*')),
    forall(between(1,Spaces, _), write(' ')),
    forall(between(1,Stars, _), write('*')),
    nl.
```

For example :

```
?- rectangle(6).
******
**  **
*    *
*    *
**  **
******
true.

?- rectangle(8).
********
***  ***
**    **
*      *
*      *
**    **
***  ***
********
true.

?- rectangle(10).
**********
****  ****
***    ***
**      **
*        *
*        *
**      **
***    ***
****  ****
**********
true.
```